# File Format Changing for POJO class using hibernate-reverse-engineering

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I am new to hibernate.I am using hibernate-reverse-engineering for POJO class creation.I have done xml class configuration. In first time POJO class created like below.

Only one file was created as Student.java

**Student.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student", schema = "dbo", catalog = "classI")
    public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long studentid;
    private String stuname;
    private Date rank;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "studentid", unique = true, nullable = false)

    public long getstudentid() {
    return this.studentid;
   }
   .................getter setter methods for all fields..........

   }
```

In second time I was running the Hibernate configuration  Student.java file was changed like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student", schema = "dbo", catalog = "classI")
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
private studentID id;

public Student () {
 }

public Student(studentID id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "stuname", column = @Column(name = "stuname")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "rank", column = @Column(name = "rank"))

        })
         public studentID getId() {
        return this.id;
        }

    public void setId(studentID id) {
     this.id = id;
     }
     }
```

**studentID.java**

```
 @Embeddable
 public class studentID implements java.io.Serializable {
 private long studentid;
    private String stuname;
    private String rank;
    public studentID () {
     }
   public studentID (String stuname, String rank) {
    this.stuname= stuname;
    this.rank= rank;
    }
    @Column(name = "stuname")
public String getstuname() {
    return this.stuname;
}

public void setstuname(String stuname) {
    this.stuname= stuname;
}

@Column(name = "rank")
public String getrank() {
    return this.rank;
}

public void setrank(String rank) {
    this.rank= rank;
}
}
```

two files created for one table.I dont know what happening here.Please i want to know the reason for why two files created for one table.Kindly guide me.

Comment: Having the same problem, ever fix yours?